# Apply function to all files in directory

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, python-2.x

I have written a function for data processing and need to apply it to a large amount of files in a directory.

The function works when applied to individual files.

```py
def getfwhm(x):    
    import numpy as np
    st=np.std(x[:,7])
    fwhm=2*np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))*st

    file=open('all_fwhm2.txt', 'at')

    file.write("fwhm = %.6f\n" % (fwhm))
    file.close()

    file=open('all_fwhm2.txt', 'rt')
    print file.read()
    file.close()
```

I now want to use this in a larger scale. So far I have written this code

```py
import os
import fwhmfunction

files=os.listdir(".")
fwhmfunction.getfwhm(files)
```

But I get the following error

```
File "fwhmfunction.py", line 11, in getfwhm
   st=np.std(x[:,7])

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I am writing in python using spyder.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of the unix You should separate the program in two:

1. the program which acts on the given file
2. the program which applies a given script to a given list of files (glob, or whatever)

So here's a sample of 1:

```
# name: script.py
import sys
File = sys.argv[1]
# do something here
print File
```

(it is better to use `argparse` to parse the args, but we used `argv` to keep it simple)

As to the second part, there is an excellent unix tool already:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "*.txt" | parallel python2.7 script.py {}
```

Here you get an extra bonus: parallel task execution.

If You on windows, then You can write something simple (sequentional) in python:

```
# name: apply_script_to_glob.py
import sys, os
from glob import glob

Script = sys.argv[1]
Glob   = sys.argv[2]

Files = glob(Glob)

for File in Files:
    os.system("python2.7 " + Script + " " + File)
```

(again we didn't use `argparse` nor checked anything to keep it simple). You'd call the script with

```
$ python2.7 apply_script_to_glob.py "script.py" "*.txt"
```